# Parsing an XML file with PowerShell where multiple elements are repeated

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm writing a script to read an XML file, example XMLFILE.XML contents below.  The script needs to parse each task and execute the executable and it's arguments if all the validations that come before each task pass their respective checks.  The attributes within each validation tag do the following: Type tells the script what information it will be checking for, Switch tells the validation whether something is true or false.  The information about the item being validated is contained within the validation element.  The free space validation below would be interpreted as "IF the C drive has 200 MB free continue, else fail." The issue I'm running into is that when I parse the XML file to get the validations I get all of them at once instead of getting one at a time that I can deal with.  I would greatly appreciate some suggestions for ways to parse the validations one at a time.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Tasks>
    <Task Name="Test task 1">
        <Validation Type="Freespace" Switch="True">C|200|MB</Validation>
        <Validation Type="Registry Key" Switch="False">HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{342C9BB8-65A0-46DE-AB7A-8031E151AF69}</Validation>
        <Validation Type="Registry Value" Switch="False">HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{342C9BB8-65A0-46DE-AB7A-8031E151AF69}|DisplayVersion|4.6.1.20870</Validation>
        <Validation Type="Service" Switch="True">ccmexec|running</Validation>       
        <Executable>notepad.exe</Executable>
        <Arguments></Arguments> 
    </Task>
    <Task Name="Test Task 2">
        <Validation Type="Registry Key" Switch="False">HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{342C9BB8-65A0-46DE-AB7A-8031E151AF69}</Validation>
        <Validation Type="Registry Value" Switch="False">HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{342C9BB8-65A0-46DE-AB7A-8031E151AF69}|DisplayVersion|4.6.1.20870</Validation>
        <Validation Type="Service" Switch="True">ccmexec|running</Validation>
        <Validation Type="Freespace" Switch="True">C|200|MB</Validation>
        <Executable>CMD.EXE</Executable>
        <Arguments>/C "ping 127.0.0.1 &amp; EXIT 33"</Arguments>    
    </Task>
</Tasks>
```

Typically, to read the XML file and parse its contents I would do something similar to the following:

```bash
[XML]$XMLALL = Get-Content ".\XMLFILE.XML"
    $Tasks = $XMLALL.Tasks

    Foreach ($item in $Tasks.Task){
    
        $Name = $item.Name
        $Validation = $item.Validation
        $Executable = $item.Executable
        $Arguments = $item.Arguments
    
        Write-host "`n Task Name: " $Name
        Write-host "Validation: " $Validation
        Write-host "Executable: " $Executable
    
    }
```

This gives the following output:

Task name:  Test task 1
Validation:
Executable:  notepad.exe

Task name:  Test Task 2
Validation:
Executable:  CMD.EXE

Comment: `XMLALL.tasks.task[0].Validation` is an array. you will have to evaluate each `Validation` element in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already doing it for each `<Task>` node. You just need to add another loop for each `<Validation>` node, like so...

```bash
[XML]$XMLALL = Get-Content ".\XMLFILE.XML"

$Tasks = $XMLALL.Tasks

Foreach ($item in $Tasks.Task)
{
    $Name = $item.Name
    $Executable = $item.Executable
    $Arguments = $item.Arguments

    Write-host "`n Task Name: " $Name
    Write-host "Executable: " $Executable

    Write-host $item.Validation.Count " Validations... "

    Foreach ($validation in $item.Validation)
    {
        Write-host "`n    Type: " $validation.Type
        Write-host "  Switch: " $validation.Switch
        Write-host "   Value: " $validation.InnerText        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank makes perfect sense now that I see it, thank you.